Wormhole for lost socks and dryer lint
I am looking for the title of a story about a spaceship that crash-lands on a planet covered with dryer lint and socks. Dryers have opening small wormholes and sending lint and small articles of clothing to one planet. The planet's surface is now buried under miles of lint and socks. Now that the ship of humans have landed and the tiny horse-like aliens know from where the debris is coming, the aliens want to attack earth for the harm suffered by their planet.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This sounds like something that Douglas Adams might have written.  Was it a short story, or part of a longer work?  When and where did you read it?

Note that IIRC there's a world of socks in Zelazny's Lord Demon, but Kai doesn't use a spaceship to get around

@DavidW Douglas Adams had a planet of lost biros, but I don't think he dealt with missing socks.

It sounds like a derivative of Litterbug. Was this from a published anthology, or an online story?

Color socks I'll wager. For the last 20yrs I've only bought plain tennis socks because, no matter how careful, the washing-up regularly ended in an odd number of them. For some arcane reason this plugged up the wormhole.

@FrançoisJurain I’ve reproduced your results but with black socks. I only buy identical black socks now, thinking that if I lose one I only need to wait until I lose a second one and then parity will be restored. But since implementing this plan, I’ve lost no socks.
